# What id_token clain to use for multi-tenant app?

Tags: openid-connect, multi-tenant

I would need to build a REST API layer for a multi-tenant system. Essentialy the users can come from different tenants and I would like to use OIDC. First I need to find out a way to identify in the token the tenant/direcatory/realm the user in coming from. Looking at JWT id_token I understand I could use the `iss` claim for that. For example with Azure AD I would find in it the tenant-ID which is what I need, but with Google I would always find the **constant** string `https://accounts.google.com`. So it looks that `iss` is not the way to go. Maybe I would need to rather process the  `aud` claim? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Google have a static issuer as they only have one "tenant" of users, while Azure AD have multiple tenants/directories. So I would use the issuer claim.